# Homotopy and homology groups in physics

Tags: topology

What is the connection between homotopy and homology groups and physics?
When does one want or need to find invariants of manifolds in physics?
Not interested in string theory.
Narrow down how? Please help. Feel free to edit

Comment: Could you narrow down this question? This currently seems like a list question, which can have potentially many answers (many things can be *recast* in homological language in mathematics already).